# Multiple custom Indices with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, indexing

I am trying to create multiple indices with multind and hyperref, as example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline, footsepline, tablecaptionabove, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
    pdftex=true,     
    backref,      
    pagebackref=false,
    hidelinks=fals,   
    bookmarks=true,         
    bookmarksopen=false,     
    bookmarksnumbered=false,    
    pdfpagemode=None]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multind}

\makeindex{Halogenalkane}
\makeindex{Alkane}

\begin{document}
\section{Wohl-Ziegler}
\index{Halogenalkane}{Wohl-Ziegler}
\section{Radikalhalogenierungen}
\index{Halogenalkane}{Radikalhalogenierungen}
\section{Radikalische Defunktionalisierung}
\index{Alkane}{Rad Def}
\section{Index nach Zielverbindungen}
\printindex{Halogenalkane}{Halogenalkane}
\printindex{Alkane}{Alkane}
\end{document}
```

But it does not print the second argument of the \index{}{} command, and neither creates an index, except for its title. I guess its a problem with hyperref and multind both modifying the \index command, but i dont know how i should implement multiple indices in another way.

Comment: The first thing you should try is to load multind before hyperref.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already tried that, to no effect.

Comment: I can't test now but wouldn't expect the \index command to print anything anyway. Regarding the empty index: did you actually run makeindex in the correct way? (btw: I would use imakeidx and not multind)

Comment: I use \makeindex{} in the preamble, compile, use makeindex, compile again. I noticed in my mwe it returns me '0 accepted 3 rejected' and in my actual project it fails to find the .idx file, the only difference is more packages and actual text in the project, i use the indexing commands exactly similar.

Comment: I just checked, multind is a very old latex 2.09 file, don't use it. Use e.g. imakeidx for your indices.